# How to use Url as parameter res.download() from expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I found a example from expressjs:
res.download('/report-12345.pdf');
to prompt the user for download. But i pass a url as parameter. It not working.

Comment: What's not working about it? Any errors or anything? Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`res.download` just accepts path to filesystem in local.

For your requirement you can do one of below:

1) use `res.redirect({URL})`

2) get that file from URL and then send file to client like :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){  
http.get(URL, function(file) {
  file.pipe(res);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That is what i want. pipe^^

Comment: Thanks, one note if the url is targeting https u should use `https.get` instead

Comment: file.pipe redirects me to the URL, how to download that file?

Comment: Before file.pipe try set headers such as:

`res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + encodeURI(fileName))`
`res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')`

Answer (score 1):

### This worked for me

```
const https = require("https");



const fileName = "the file name" + ".mp4";

https.get(url, function (file) {
     res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + encodeURI(fileName));
     res.set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
     file.pipe(res);
});
```

Here select the **[Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)** for you file

Here's a **[list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-content-type/)** of mostly all **content type**

---

In the **fileName** add the **file extension** of your file i.e. ( **.jpg** , **.png** , **.txt**)

Answer (score -2):

The first parameter to the `res.download()` method is the absolute path to the file on the filesystem, not a network URL. So if you say `res.download('/report-12345.pdf');` you are trying to download the `report-12345.pdf` file from the root folder of your filesystem.